# How to optimze error handling for SQLiteOpenHelper

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

Is it possible to do error handling is more clear and more readable? My version seems like a bit bulky:

```
public synchronized void doSomeTrans(...) throws Exception {
    Exception ex = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;
    boolean bTrans = false;

    try {
        db = getWritableDatabase();

        db.beginTransaction();
        bTrans = true;

        db.execSQL(...);
        db.execSQL(...);

        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    catch (Exception ex1) {
        ex = ex1;
    }

    if (db != null) {
        if (bTrans != false)
            db.endTransaction();

        db.close();
    }

    if (ex != null)
        throw ex;
}
```

Also, in my version I don't have any error handling around endTransaction method and if this method throws exception my database still exists opened. I think it's not good, but not sure that adding new on try/catch block is best solution for this case.

Answer (score 2):

If nothing else, you should be using `finally`. You are throwing the exception further anyway, so don't bother catching it at all:

```
try {
    db = getWritableDatabase();
    ...
} finally {
    if (db != null) {
        if (bTrans != false)
            db.endTransaction();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

The other thing is that you shouldn't open the database for the one operation and close it again, because that is *SLOW*. You should have the `db` around for at least life-time of the `Activity` or `Service`. Which gets rid of the outer `getWritableDatabase()`/`close` pair, so you are down to:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    db.execSQL(...);
    db.execSQL(...);

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

Note, that that's not getting to the `endTransaction` if `beginTransaction` throws, which can easily happen. I am not sure about the Android wrapper, because I normally use the C API, but the C API does not wait for locking the database, but fails straight away when the database is locked by another transaction already.

Obviously RAII or context manager would be even shorter, but unfortunately Java does not have either (Update: Java 8 does have `try(variable)`, but Android is stuck with Java 6; it should, however, be supported in Kotlin even for that target).

Comment: If getWritableDatabase is not needed, how is db declared if not by db = getWritableDatabase()?

Comment: @seekingStillness, it *is* needed. I was just saying that you should keep one around in a member of the activity or service rather than creating it for each operation.